# speed up autoconf/configure of large project

Tags: autoconf, automake

I have a large autoconf/automake project, broken into components using AC_CONFIG_SUBDIRS.  Is there any way to make autoconf/configure run faster?  Perhaps doing subdirs in parallel, or caching reusable findings?

I could easily write a build script that would build components in parallel, but would prefer to not add a secondary point of build structure maintainance.

Answer (score 9):

You can **cache results** between multiple `configure` (several runs of the same `configure`, or recursive sub-`configure`) using the [configure cache feature](http://www.gnu.org/s/hello/manual/autoconf/Cache-Files.html).  Simply run

```
./configure -C
```

However you should remember to delete the cache when your system's configuration changes (like after installing new packages that were not found by a previous configure run).  If you use some third-party macros, you may also have to fix some of them to [cache their results](http://www.gnu.org/s/hello/manual/autoconf/Caching-Results.html#Caching-Results) properly (a common error is to make some configuration decision during a test that might be skipped if the result of that test is cached).

If you want to share your cache between multiple projects, you can set it up in [`config.site`](http://www.gnu.org/s/hello/manual/autoconf/Site-Defaults.html).

Comment: Agreed on just about all counts, but setting cache variables in `config.site` strikes me as a Bad Idea. Didn't gentoo try a confcache a few years back? IIRC, they had to back it out because it broke heaps of things.

Answer (score 5):

I'm thinking of a **parallel** configure which does the checks in parallel making best use of the multicore of the host. Probably the autoconf should generate bash script which can be vectorized/pipelined to make it possible.